# Column does not belong to table (Multi word query)

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

I have this problem when I try to read a query with multiple words.
Basically after selecting item from combo box I put string value to query and exetute it. 
It works fine when I select 1 word items however if I select multiple words items it throws me error:

```
Column 'Eligible for free meals' does not belong to table Eligible for free meals.
```

`'Eligible for free meels'` stands for selected item. I tried to put `%` and remove single quote but it did not helped... Can anyone help me with this problem. Im just a beginner and don't know much about c#....

```
        string Column = Filter1.Text;
        Filter1Values.Items.Clear();
        string Query = "select '" + Column + "' from [data$]";
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(Query, con);            
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(ds, Column);
        dt = ds.Tables[Column];
        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            string value = dt.Rows[i][Column].ToString();
            if (!Filter1Values.Items.Contains(value))
            {
                Filter1Values.Items.Add(value);
            }
        }
```

Thank you! Sorry if format is not in appropriate format I'm new here...

Comment: try with "[Eligible for free meels]" as column name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have surrounded the table name in square brackets it seems you are using MSSQL. So, because your column names can contains spaces you should do the same with them, like this...

```
string Query = "select [" + Column + "] from [data$]";
```

For Oracle, it would be...

```
string Query = "select \"" + Column + "\" from data$";
```

For MySQL, it would be...

```
string Query = "select `" + Column + "` from data$";
```